# Project Connection is not found for OleDbSource using Biml

Tags: ssis, biml

I am having an issue when I generate a package with biml which references a project level connection manager.  The connection manager is not found for an OleDb Source, but works fine in a SQL task.  Additionally, package level connection managers work fine.

Here is example code:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="sql" ConnectionString="data source=.;initial catalog=Staging;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=sspi;" />
    </Connections>
    <Projects>
        <PackageProject Name="Test">
            <Packages>
                <Package PackageName="MyPackage2"/>
            </Packages>
            <Connections>
                <Connection ConnectionName="sql"/>
            </Connections>
        </PackageProject>
    </Projects>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="MyPackage2">
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL Name="TestSQL" ConnectionName="sql">
                    <DirectInput>
                        Select 1
                    </DirectInput>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <Dataflow Name="My Dataflow">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource Name="Read" ConnectionName ="sql">
                            <DirectInput>
                                Select 1 as Test;
                            </DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

When generated the OleDbSource has the following error:

> Validation error. My Dataflow Read [2]: The runtime connection manager
>   with the ID "{6253281E-98BA-45C3-ACAB-BC58B34CC627}" cannot be found.
>   Verify that the connection manager collection has a connection manager
>   with that ID.

I have tried a number of different things which did not help:

- Set CreateInProject to true for the connection manager
- Used Connection as well as OleDbConnection
- Added the Connections collection to the package and referenced the connection

What am I missing?

Comment: I tested your BIML and it works fine for me.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert this is odd.  If I delete the connection manager from the project and regenerate, it's ok.  But if I regenerate when it again, while the CM already exists, the CM is not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy an pasted your BIML and it generated all files without error. When I made a change and regenerated the files I received the same error message you did.

To resolve the issue I deleted the connection manager manually then regenerated the files. I am not sure what is causing this to happen but it this is a reliable work around to get the package working again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  I was expecting something as simple as this to just work, so I hadn't googled too much.  However, there is an extensive explanation here: https://varigence.com/Forums?threadID=9656.  Hopefully this will be fixed soon.